# Visual Studio - Outgoing Commits - Push option disabled

Tags: git, visual-studio

Wasted way too much time on this... I can't seem to get my local branch to the remote

Example (all done from VS2019 gui)

1. Select team explorer
2. Click Branches
3. Create branch from Master and checkout branch
4. Make change to a file, go to team explorer.
5. Click changes, select "Commit all and sync"

Message says: Unable to sync because the current branch does not track a remote branch. Push the branch to sync changes with the remote.

6. Here's the kicker - from documentation is says for first time, click the "push" link in the outgoing commits to resolve the issue.

The PUSH under outgoing commits is DISABLED!

All inputs appreciated... Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 10):

In my case I had to re-start VS to fix!

Answer (score 1):

Just had this with a new install of VS with an AWS CodeCommit repo.

When you load VS you get a bar at the top of the Git Changes window asking you to Login - it just confirms your user name etc. The banner disappears quite quickly when you are using VS so just close and re-open it to get it back.

Once I confirmed my details I could sync correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem appeared, when I tried opening a project in VS2019 for which I have created a Git repo externally (using GitExtensions) with a valid remote. TeamExplorer refused to show "Push" option. Only commit/stash was possible. Same message as your point #5. There were some subtle differences in the CONFIG file in the .git folder.

I could fix it by opening a "blank" VS2019 and cloning the project from remote repo into another folder. After that "push" option was available and worked.

You have to copy your modified files/code portions manually. Depends on your project size whether to consider this option.